# Delayed push notifications and checking if user enabled it

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I develop an app, which builds itself around push notifications. The app requests notification permissions only when the user reaches certain point of the registration process. I have already managed to do the following:

- the app maintains an `NSUserDefaults` variable, which indicates if it is required to register for push at launch or not (by default: not)
- when the registration reaches that point, I flip the variable and call `-registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` on iOS 7 and `-registerUserNotificationSettings:` on iOS 8

This works fine unless the user has already enabled push notifications and then disabled them later in the Settings. In this case I try to reregister Push at launch, which does not call either `-application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` nor `-application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`.

Additional information, that iOS 8's `-isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` also returns `YES`. (I did not test but suppose that `-enabledNotificationTypes` works upto iOS 7.)

How can I detect this scenario and present the user a requester which asks him to reenable notifications in the Settings?

Comment: I am seeing this problem as well and it does appear to be a bug.

Comment: @gklka did you manage to fix this? I am also facing the issue.

Comment: @anoop4real, I came across this issue as well, this is what I did for workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32448982/1473984

Comment: @ewiinnnnn thanks for the help and now I know the reason for getting TRUE always. My intention here is to find out whether settings was turned off manually by the user or the settings were never there, accordingly I need to do certain actions. NotificationTypes will return None in both cases so I won't able to decide whether to try a register or to show the user a link to settings. It is kind of a tricky usecase.

Answer (score 6):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
```

> Returns a Boolean indicating whether the app is currently registered
>   for remote notifications.
>
> Declaration SWIFT func isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications() -> Bool
>   OBJECTIVE-C
>   - (BOOL)isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications Return Value YES if the app is registered for remote notifications and received its device token
>   or NO if registration has not occurred, has failed, or has been denied
>   by the user.
>
> Discussion This method reflects only the successful completion of the
>   remote registration process that begins when you call the
>   registerForRemoteNotifications method. This method does not reflect
>   whether push notifications are actually available due to connectivity
>   issues. **The value returned by this method takes into account the
>   user’s preferences for receiving push notifications.**
>
> Availability Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

[Link to Apple Doc's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)

I would file a bug report at Apple.

Comment: Thank you. This code works only until iOS 8, because `-enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` is now deprecated. My other problem is that when do I need to call this code? If I call it in `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, then it runs _before_ my push registration delegate methods (`didRegister`/`failedToRegister`) get called. I don't think using a timer would do either. I also can't put it into the `didRegister`, because it might not get called at all.

Comment: Check my edit for iOS8, you can fire you're checking method whenever you want. In your main UIViewController f.e. At the point you are sure they should have registered for PN

Comment: You did not read my question carefully. This method always returns `YES` for me, no matter the user turned on or off the notifications.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see the iOS8 question at first. According to the docs it should however take the users preferences into account when returning its value.