# Is there a way to know that the user refused to recieve push notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification

There is a similar question, but the answer dosn't satisfy me at all.

[iOS7 and iOS8: how to detect when user said No to a request for push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161645/ios7-and-ios8-how-to-detect-when-user-said-no-to-a-request-for-push-notificatio)

I need to know specifically what the user chose when relevant popup was shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Luda -

That question that you are referencing gives a two part answer - it depends on your iOS version. If you are using iOS7, which it does not appear to be the case based on your screenshot, you will not get a callback whatsoever. But if you are using iOS 8 (and presumably 9), you will get a call to

```
application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings
```

whether the user pressed OK or Don't Allow. Starting in iOS 8 you will need to parse the UIUserNotificationSettings parameter passed to that callback to determine whether or not the user accepted or denied the push notifications.

Comment: application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings is not called when you press "Don't allow"

Comment: @Luda, you must be implementing something incorrectly because didRegisterUserNotificationSettings is called when the user clicks on "Don't Allow" (or OK, for that matter).  You will be able to read notificationSettings and compare it to .None to see if the user denied.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this a few seconds after requesting for push notifications - `UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications()`

**Bear in mind that you can only do this for >iOS8 - otherwise you are not going to know**

This returns a `Bool`, you can do as you wish with the result.

I have previously used this in the AppDelegate when the app is opened in the Foreground, Example:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        let isRegistered = UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications()
        if !isRegistered {
             // The user has not allowed pushes
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to be notified WHEN the user declines Push, not WHAT did he chose (except or decline)