# How can I know that receiving Push Notification wasn't offered yet?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can I know if user wasn't offered to receive Push Notifications yet?

The following code will tell me that the user didn't agree to pushed, but it can be due to refusal or due to the fact that receiving push notifications popup wasn't offered yet.

How do I know the difference?

```
if let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
{
    if (settings.types == UIUserNotificationType.None)
    {
        self.promtForApplePush()
        // do stuff 
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can remember you cannot differentiate between the two cases without you saving internally that you already have shown the dialog before.

Comment: either offered great but if not..then get your way off....because as of app store guidelines"5.3
Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user consent, as well as apps that require Push Notifications to function, will be rejected"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS7 and iOS8: how to detect when user said No to a request for push notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161645/ios7-and-ios8-how-to-detect-when-user-said-no-to-a-request-for-push-notificatio)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for.

> Check the value `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` on the `UIApplication` object

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27162814/2753395

Comment: It's a Bool. If it is false you won't know if the user already refused or didn't chose anything else, because he wasn't offered to receive push notifications