# iOS 8+ Remote notification capability always enabled

Tags: ios

For iOS >= 8, only

In my AppDelegate, I register for user notifications as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions called");

    // iOS >= 8.0

    // register to receive user notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    ...
}
```

Upon completion, I register for remote notification as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    NSLog(@"didRegisterUserNotificationSettings called");

    //register to receive remote notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

And upon completion, I check to see whether the app is registered

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called");

    BOOL pushNotificationOnOrOff = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]; // always returns TRUE
}
```

But app always indicates that push notification is enabled, even when the user has explicitly set the app's remote notification capability off (via the notification permissions alert that appears after first time installation of the app, or via app settings.)

I have set the app's Background Modes / Remote Notifications to TRUE. I have been debugging on an actual device (tethered via USB cable) compiled with a development certificate.

Help, I've been battling this for hours.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug, I also discovered the same behaviour on iPhone 6, iOS 8.1.2.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]` always returns `TRUE` even if user declined the push notification permission (via the alert view) or by manually disabling the notification via `Settings.app > Notifications`.

After some research I discovered that if you have `Background App Refresh` enabled for the app, then `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]` will always returns `TRUE`.

When `Background App Refresh` set to `FALSE` then `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]` returns the correct value.

As a workaround, you can evaluate the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings].types` to determine whether the push notification is allowed or not.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIUserNotificationType) {
    UIUserNotificationTypeNone    = 0,      // the application may not present any UI upon a notification being received
    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0, // the application may badge its icon upon a notification being received
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1, // the application may play a sound upon a notification being received
    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2, // the application may display an alert upon a notification being received
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just want to comment quick that I have observed this same behaviour in an app I am working on now, running on iPhone 5S 9.2.1. When Background Refresh is off, this value returns true or false as expected. When Background Refresh is on, this value only returns true.